# Even though the numbers too large, it's still being processed (ignore, I fixed it)

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.io.*;
```

import java.util.*;

public class CH04 {

```
// Constants Declaration Section
//******************************

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Variables Declaration Section
    //******************************
    int  quarters;
    int  dimes;
    int  nickles;
    int  numberOfQuarters;
    int  numberOfDimes;
    int remainingAmount; 
    int numberOfNickles;
    int numberOfPennies;
    int maxSize;

    // Variables Initialization Section
    //*********************************
    Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("C:\\testing3.txt"));     //Reads from text file 
    ArrayList<Double> datadata = new ArrayList<Double>();    //Creates Array
    quarters = 25;
    dimes = 10;
    nickles = 5;
    maxSize = 10000;



    // Code Section
    //*************
    while(data.hasNextDouble())    //Retrieves data from text file and places it in array
    {
        datadata.add(data.nextDouble());  //Retrieves data from text file and places it in array
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < datadata.size(); i++)  //Loops through the data
    {
        double value = datadata.get(i);   //returns number found in file as a double 'value' then runs it through the calculator
        System.out.println(value);

        while(value > maxSize) //If value is greater than 10,000, it will be skipped and not read through the calculator
        {

        }

        remainingAmount = (int)Math.ceil((value) * 100);      //multiplies value by 100

        numberOfQuarters = remainingAmount / quarters;   //divides value by 25
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % quarters;    //returns the remaining value 

        numberOfDimes = remainingAmount / dimes;    //divides the remaining value by 10
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % dimes;  //returns the remaining value of that

        numberOfNickles = remainingAmount / nickles;  //divides the remaining value from dimes by 5
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % nickles;  //returns remaining value

        numberOfPennies = remainingAmount;   //divides remaining value by 1


        System.out.print("Your amount of $" + value + " consists of: \n" + numberOfQuarters +            //prints out the amount of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies
                " quarteres, " + numberOfDimes + " dimes, " + numberOfNickles + " nickles, and " +       //that make up each value found inside the file.
                  numberOfPennies + " pennies");

        System.out.print("\n\n");

    }



    //Output Section
    //**************




    //Resource Cleaning
    //*****************
    data.close();

}
```

}

```
**Output:
```

10001.0
Value is too large to be processed 10001.0
Your amount of $10001.0 consists of: 
40004 quarteres, 0 dimes, 0 nickles, and 0 pennies

9755.35
Your amount of $9755.35 consists of: 
39021 quarteres, 1 dimes, 0 nickles, and 0 pennies

875.4
Your amount of $875.4 consists of: 
3501 quarteres, 1 dimes, 1 nickles, and 0 pennies

78.99
Your amount of $78.99 consists of: 
315 quarteres, 2 dimes, 0 nickles, and 4 pennies

5.0
Your amount of $5.0 consists of: 
20 quarteres, 0 dimes, 0 nickles, and 0 pennies

0.7
Your amount of $0.7 consists of: 
2 quarteres, 2 dimes, 0 nickles, and 0 pennies

Values being used: [10001.0, 9755.35, 875.4, 78.99, 5.0, 0.7]
    **

For some reason I am receiving 1 penny less for the italicized portion of the output. It's confusing me because the rest of the output is correct.

The values inside my text value are:

```
10,001.00 -
9,755.35 -
875.40 -
78.99 -
5.00 -
0.70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not write about the code itself. I guess that it is handmade as an example. The general rule of thumb of debugging for such a problem is: look at the very end or at the very start'.
The division is working correctly, hence must it happen at the very start and that is where your value is casted into an int. If you check the result of the product of value * 100, then will you see 7898.999999999999, not 7899 as you expected. You should use Math.ceil to get the correct value like this:

```
 int result = (int)Math.ceil(value * 100);
```

Comment: Hey, I did this and it fixed my issue for the 78.99 output (gave me the 4 pennies like it should instead of 3. Thank you!

Sorry for the late response, I fell asleep..

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with floating point arithmetic error.
If you print out the `value * 100`, you'll notice it comes out to 7898.9999...
Floating point arithmetic error is only off by a very small amount when it occurs.

The simple solution for your case would be to just add `.1` and then cast to an int.

Change this line:

```
remainingAmount = (int)(value * 100);
```

to:

```
remainingAmount = (int)(value * 100 + .1);
```

The only way to break this is if the test file contained values that use more than 2 decimal places. But since you're dealing with money, you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: I would of done this but it would change all my outputs...